# como fazer asim que a pagina dar refresh minha variavel em js não mudar

Tags: javascript, html, front-end

eu tenho um código html

```html
<div id="nome"> nome </div>
```

e um js que pergunta o usuário o nome e reescreve a div

```js
var username = prompt('qual seu nome ?');

alert('olá ' + username + ', seja bem vindo <3')

document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML = username;
```

e queria fazer com que esse código so seja lido a primeira vez que meu usuário entre e que dando refresh na page não reescreva mais a minha div

Comment: Para isso, você precisa salvar esse nome em algum lugar. Nesse caso parece que pode ser no próprio computador de quem está acessando, em um cookie ou no localstorage.

Comment: aplicando um setTimeout.. acredito q resolve..

Answer (score 2):

Tendo em vista que você está iniciando, recomendo que estudo sobre gerenciamento de estado, padrão muito utilizado no desenvolvimento dos frameworks web, como por exemplo React, Angular e etc.

Porém, neste caso podemos resolver de forma simples, salvando no [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)a informação.

```js
if(localStorage.getItem("name")){
   alert("Olá " +  localStorage.getItem("name"));
}
else{
   var username = prompt("qual seu nome ?");
   localStorage.setItem("name", username);
   alert("Olá " +  localStorage.getItem("name"));
}
```

Comment: Poderia melhorar o estilo de codificação obtendo inicialmente `localStorage.getItem("name")` em uma variável e fazer o teste com o valor dessa variável e aproveitar ou não esse valor conforme o teste.